# Mac running High Sierra getting notices to Upgrade to Mojave. Can I install to an external SSD instead of the host iMac?

Tags: hard-drive, mac, usb, ssd

I've got a 2013 iMac running High Sierra 10.13.6. I keep getting notifications to upgrade to Mojave (which I don't want to do), but I would like to install Mojave onto an SSD for use in a laptop I have. I have a USB 3.0 to SATA cable to make the connection.

Here's my question. Can I select the SSD via the USB after I initiate the upgrade via App Store, or will it automatically install Mojave onto the iMac's internal HDD?

Answer (score 0):

If you run it straight from the "Install macOS Mojave" app in the Applications folder, it will update the existing OS.

To persuade it to install on another drive you will need to boot from a USB stick. That way you get a disk picker as part of the process.

Use `createinstallmedia` to make the USB from the Install macOS app. Full details at Apple KB - [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)

Comment: Thanks!  I thought that might be the case but always looking for the easy way...